# C# Windows form App with SharePoint

Tags: c#, xml, sharepoint

Im new to the whole C# and Visual Studio program. 
I have been given a task to create a windows form app using C# to connect to a SharePoint site and retrieve any data from there e.g. list, files. 
I have designed my application so that you can manually add the site url which you want then click a button and this will generate a xml file with all the data which is in the site. 
This is the way i need my xml to be set out:

The report should be in either csv or xml format e.g.

```
<SiteCollection Name=”SiteCollection”>

<Web Name=”Web Name”>

<Library Name=”Library Name”>

<Document Name=”DocName1”/>

<Folder Name=”Folder Name”>

<Document Name=”DocName2”/>

<Document Name=”DocName3”/>

</Folder>

</Library>

<List Name=”List Name”>

<Web Name=”Web Name”>

<Library Name=”Library Name”>

<Document Name=”DocName1”/>

<Folder Name=”Folder Name”>

<Document Name=”DocName2”/>

<Document Name=”DocName3”/>

</Folder>

</Library>

<List Name=”List Name”>

</Web>

</Web>

</SiteCollection>
```

This is how I have my code for my app set out so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;


namespace SharePoint.College
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

} 
}
}
```

Im just looking for some advice and some help to start this off.

Thanks for any replies

Comment: Actually I can't see any code there!

Comment: @VahidND the bottom snippet is of the display I get when I look at code view within visual Studio

Comment: Take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2007/09/15/how-to-download-files-from-a-sharepoint-document-library-remotely-via-lists-asmx-webservice-sps-2003-moss-2007.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As your new to this you should start with a few basic tutorials, a search for C# tutorials will turn up loads of results. You could start with [MSDN C# Tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Once you are comfortable with C# take a look at some Winforms tutorials such as [C# Corner - Tutorial: Working with Windows Forms - Part I](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jmukharjee/WindowsFormsTutorial111282005011245AM/WindowsFormsTutorial1.aspx)

Assuming you are using SharePoint 2010 and you are not going to be running this code directly on the SharePoint server you will want to look at [Using the SharePoint Foundation 2010 Managed Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094%28v=office.14%29.aspx) in order to retrieve the information.

As a side note you will get better responses from this site if you do this kind of research first and then ask questions (with relevant code snippets) about specific difficulties you are encountering, see [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) on the help pages.

Answer (score -1):

This code should give you access to a List or Library. Note that since you are a beginner, you may not be familiar with handling SPList so I have converted to a DataTable which I believe should be easier. Note that I have named the member variables (those starting with this.xxx)to indicate what they are/should contain.

```
   using (SPSite site = new SPSite(this.siteUrl))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(this.siteName))
        {
            SPList mylib = web.Lists[this.libraryName];
            DataTable dt = mylib.Items.GetDataTable();
        }
    }
```

In the mean time please follow Aquila Sands suggestions, it pays off in the long run if you decide to stay with C# and SharePoint. Good luck.